# I need help with backingup data and doing a factory reset

Tags: backup, nextbook-premium-8

How do i back up data for apps, such as games? If so,is it safe to factory data reset? I'm basically wanting to know how to save my data and still be able to reset my tablet.

Comment: I've just added the `backup` tag to your question. For a starter, you might wish to check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info).

Answer (score 1):

In order to save apps' data you have two options:

- If your phone is rooted, use the famous app [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=it);
- If your phone is NOT rooted, use [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=it) with a Windows PC.

Comment: How do i find out if it's rooted?

Comment: @valerie Rooting is something you have to do deliberately, so if you don't know, then it isn't rooted.